# Query in xml files to select value from node

Tags: java, xml, xpath

As an example, this is the kind of xml file I have:

```
<Node>
    <Sample A>
        ...
    </Sample A>
    <Sample B>
        <myType>importantValue</myType>
    </Sample B>
    ...
    <Sample Z>
        <myValue>16</myValue>
    </Sample Z>
<Node>
    <Sample A>
        ...
    </Sample A>
    <Sample B>
        <myType>importantValue</myType>
    </Sample B>
    ...
    <Sample Z>
        <myValue>16</myValue>
    </Sample Z>
```

How do I make a query similar to "Select myType and myValue where myValue > x"?

I am trying to use xPath to find the right element, and I am sure there is an easy way to do it, but as I am new to queries in XML I dont find a simple way.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what did you try so far? a whole, executable code snippet would be good

Comment: String expression = "/Node/SampleB/myType
String type= xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc);

But then I am not sure how I get the node element..? And its children..?

Comment: Can you post your code here ?

Comment: This isn't well-formed XML. Does each `<Sample>` element have an identifier? What do the `A`, `B`, `Z`s mean? Are you simply looking for two `Node` elements with `Samples` with the right `myValue` values?

Comment: Yeah I know the XML is not well-formed, but this is what I have to work with ;)

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps. Hope you didn't missed out them.

**Create a Document from a file or stream**

```
StringBuilder xmlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
xmlStringBuilder.append("<?xml version="1.0"?> <class> </class>");
ByteArrayInputStream input =  new ByteArrayInputStream(
   xmlStringBuilder.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
Document doc = builder.parse(input);
```

**Build XPath**

```
XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
```

**Prepare Path expression and evaluate it**

```
String expression = "/Node/SampleB";            
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

**Iterate over NodeList**

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
   Node nNode = nodeList.item(i);
   ...
}
```

**Examine attributes**

```
//returns specific attribute
getAttribute("attributeName"); 
//returns a Map (table) of names/values
getAttributes();
```

**Examine sub-elements**

```
//returns a list of subelements of specified name
getElementsByTagName("subelementName"); 
//returns a list of all child nodes
getChildNodes();
```

In your case,

```
String expression = "/Node/SampleB";
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node nNode = nodeList.item(i);
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
               Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
               System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("myType")
                     .item(0).getTextContent());}}
```

Comment: can I do something like

String expression = "/Node";            
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);


nodeList.getElementsByTagName("SampleB").getAttribute("myType");


?

Comment: See my added snippet at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your XML is structured like this:

```
<Node>
  <Sample>
    <someValue>sharks</someValue>
  </Sample>
  <Sample>
    <myValue>16</myValue>
  </Sample>
  <Sample>
    <myType>importantValue</myType>
  </Sample>
</Node>
<Node>
  ...
</Node>
...
```

And `Samples` are grouped by `Node` elements, then what you want is to find a specific `Node` with the properties you want, and then find the values from that same `Node` that you want.

Here's an XPath expression that gets a `Node` by `Sample/myValue`:

```
//Node[Sample/myValue = '16']
```

This reads as "get all `Nodes` whose child `Sample`'s child `myValue`'s value is `'16'`".

You can add to it to get different values:

```
//Node[Sample/myValue = '16']/Sample/myType
```

This changes the return value of the XPath expression, it reads as "get the value from `myType`, whose parent is `Sample`, whose parent is a `Node` whose `Sample/myValue`'s value is `'16'`".

To get multiple values out of an XPath expression, you can use the `|` operator to combine multiple expressions together:

```
//Node[Sample/myValue = '16'] | //Node[Sample/myValue = '15']
```

This reads as "get all `Nodes` whose `Sample/myValue` value is `'16'` or `'15'`".